# Able to run script directly on host but not via Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a script that basically pssh into multiple hosts for some information and checks a file to see if the information matches or not. The script runs fine when run directly from the Jenkins node. But when I try to run it via Jenkins, it hangs. It does create the output file, I added debug statements and see that the hosts from the file.txt are getting printed on Jenkins, but otherwise it just hangs. 
I'm passing the file name as one of the arg. On Jenkins, I used to string parameter to pass the file. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import re
import datetime

try:
  hosts_file = sys.argv[1]
  with open(hosts_file, 'r') as f:
    hosts = []
    for line in f:
      hosts.append(line.split()[0])
except IOError:
  print 'Error opening hosts_file'
  sys.exit(1)

for host in hosts:
    cmd = ('sshpass -f password pssh -A -O UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -O StrictHostKeyChecking=no -H ' + host + ' -l root  -i "<cmd>"')
    with open('file.txt', 'w') as fw:
      subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True, stdout=fw)
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as fr:

  for line in fr:
        match = re.search(r'some_word', line, re.I)
        if match:
          id_list.append(line.split()[-1])
          model_dict[id_list[-1]] = line.strip()

    if len(id_list) == 0:
      print "something not found for hostname =>  %s" % host

    with open('file.txt', 'r') as fr, open('output', 'a') as fw:
      fw.write("something ==> %s" % host + "\n")

fw.write("*****************************************************************************************************************************************************************" + "\n")
      for line in fr:
        for item in id_list:
          match = re.search(r'%s' % item, line, re.I)
          if match:
            my_line = model_dict[item] + '  => ' +  line
            fw.write(my_line)
            id_list.remove(item)

    if len(id_list) > 0:
      with open('output', 'a') as fw:
        for item in id_list:
          my_line = model_dict[item] + ' => ' + 'No match found'
          fw.write(my_line + "\n")

    with open('models.txt', 'r') as fr, open('output', 'a') as fw:
      fw.write("#### Printing Controller information ####" + "\n")
      for line in fr:
        match = re.search(r'vmhba', line, re.I)
        if match:
          fw.write(line.strip() + "\n")

    os.remove('models.txt')
#I'm assuming this will print on the Jenkins console
with open('output', 'r') as fr:
  for line in fr:
    print line
```

Comment: The files.txt is getting created but is empty. So looks like the pssh is not working. But its working when run directly on the host.

Comment: Is it because the pssh module needs to be imported and my host has that, so it's working fine from the host directly but somehow jenkins is using Python from elsewhere which doesn't have that module and hence it is failing. How do I set Jenkins to use my host's Python?